# How to check for a list item and the one after it in a list of integers

Tags: python, list, sum, integer

So I want to keep a subtotal but I want to subtract the number from the subtotal if it's smaller than the one to its right.

Example:

```
   for i in list:
        if i < i+1:
            num += int(i)
        else:   
            num -= int(i)
    return num
```

I wanted this code to give me 397 but it adds the 10, doesn't subtract it

Comment: What do you think `i+1`  and why `i < i+1` would be ever false?

Comment: `i+1` is not the next value in your list.  It's one more than the current value in the list.  As such, it will always be greater than `i`.  If you want to compare consecutive list values, there are a couple ways to do it.  The simplest is probably to iterate a list index `ix`, then index into the list using subscripts `i` and `i+1`.  Also, don't use `list` as a variable name.  It will mask the builtin.

Comment: I wouldn't call your list `list`, since that's the name of the builtin `list()` constructor in Python. Call it... `lst`, `my_list`... Something. Also, I think you are using `i` as the list index (in which case you should do `my_list[i]` and `my_list[i+1]`, because the way that `for` is written will iterate over the elements contained in the list, not over the indices.

Comment: How can i get the value of the next item in the list then?

Comment: @BorrajaX No, `list` is not a reserved keyword.  If it were, it would not be possible to assign to it.  It's the name of a builtin.  There's a big difference.  Reserved keywords are things like `class`, `if`, `for`, `def`, etc.  You can't assign to those.

Comment: Instead of writing comments could you provide some code so I can better understand?

Comment: Very true and interesting, @TomKarzes thank you! (edited and corrected my comment)

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, I think you want to iterate over the list *indexes*, not the list *values*.  Then you can easily use the index to fetch the *current* value and the *next* value.

```
mylist = [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    curval = mylist[i]
    if i < len(mylist) - 1:
        nextval = mylist[i+1]
        if curval < nextval:
            num += int(curval)
        else:   
            num -= int(curval)
    else:
        num += int(curval)
return num
```

Comment: @QueensGambyte True, I deliberately used `range(len(mylist) - 1)` so that it wouldn't try to access `mylist[i+1]` on the last index, thus causing an out-of-bounds exception.  I'll edit the answer to address this.

Comment: list index out of range

Comment: @QueensGambyte I don't get any such error on this code.  I have edited it a few times, make sure you're using the current code.

Comment: I did this https://imgur.com/8kZrbbL and it still adds the 10 idk why

Comment: That code is iterating over the list _values_, which was the same problem your original question had...

Comment: Ok  but i want my code to be as simple as this, is that possible?

Comment: You should be able to use this code exactly as-is.  Did you try that?

Comment: I got 395 instead of 396, so it failed to add the last 1

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to build tuples of the values. `zip` gets the original list and a copy with an offset of 1 as parameters. This idea might not be the best if the list is large.

```
data = [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1]

total = 0
for left_value, right_value in zip(data, data[1:]]):
    if left_value < right_value:
        total -= left_value
    else:
        total += left_value
print(total)
```

The result is 396, but you wanted 397. So what's wrong? The last element in the list has no matching value because the list with the offset misses one element. But that's an easy fix. Just add the last element again.

```
for left_value, right_value in zip(data, data[1:] + [data[-1]]):
```

---

Alternative approach with a one-liner:

```
total = sum(-left if left < right else left for left, right in zip(data, data[1:] + [data[-1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using this.

```
l = [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1]
length = len(l)
num = 0
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    if value < l[index + 1 if index < length - 1 else index]:
        num -= int(value)
    else:   
        num += int(value)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple could be this:

```
ls = [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1]

num = 0

for i, v in enumerate(ls):
    try:
        if ls[i] < ls[i+1]:
            num -= v
    except:
        pass
```

The manage exception is to avoid the an IndexError

Output:

```
-10
```

Comment: what does "for i, v" do?

Comment: i, v inside a for loop with the enumerate function, assigns to 'i' a counter (the iteration index) and to 'v' the value of the iterable. Here you can see the information better: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to iterate over consecutive pairs of items in a list is to `zip` the list with a slice of itself.  Using `sum` and a simple ternary expression you can write this in one line:

```
>>> nums = [100, 100, 100, 10, 100, 5, 1, 1]  # don't call a list "list"
>>> sum(a if a >= b else -a for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:])) + nums[-1]
397
```

Note that `nums[-1]` is a special case since it has no consecutive number `b`, and here we're choosing to add it to the sum unconditionally.